# How to order by a column with specific order in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have this table

```
name        level
Dion        Leader
Roy         Member
Gerald      Member
Boyz        Assistant
Jade        Member
Gulliver    Leader
Ananda      Assistant
Vervada     Member
```

I'd like to do `ORDER BY` in this table. So, the first that is show is Leader, then assistant, then member AND it's ordered by they name too.

The output I'm looking for:

```
name        level
Dion        Leader
Gulliver    Leader
Ananda      Assistant
Boyz        Assistant
Gerald      Member
Jade        Member
Roy         Member
Vervada     Member
```

my current query is (not give correct output though) :

```
SELECT name,level FROM t_user ORDER BY level='Leader' DESC, level='Assistant' DESC
```

Note: If possible, the query is has to be as light/fast as possible. Because the t_user has 5k++ rows.

Comment: 5k rows isn't very much.

Comment: well, the real table column is not just two, and there are JOINS too.

Comment: Your own query works fine too.